# Connecting to activeMQ using camel blueprint

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'm using Camel blueprint on JBoss Developer studio, which is a new challenge for me.

I've googled and found stuff like this: http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html but what I'm trying to figure out is how you define your activeMQ connection if you're using the blueprint. Everything references and activeMQ bean, but nothing shows how to define it in the blueprint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an ActiveMQComponent outside the the camel context :

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">

    <bean id="activemq"
          class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
      <property name="brokerURL"
                value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
    </bean>

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
      ...
    </camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

Note that this is described as "spring XML configuration" in http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html. The blueprint XML schema is mostly the same as the one for Spring (you can list main differences at http://camel.apache.org/using-osgi-blueprint-with-camel.html), so in most case you can use what is described as "spring xml" in blueprint.